# linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic but it is not installable

Tags: 18.04

when I execute the command **sudo apt upgrade**, the terminal showed the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is installed
 linux-image-4.15.0-126-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and when i try **sudo apt --fix-broken install** I received the following answer

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-126 linux-headers-4.15.0-126-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-129 linux-headers-4.15.0-129-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-129-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-129-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-129-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-126-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2 832 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8 419 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 259024 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is the question? Also what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry about that ... my version of Ubuntu is 18.04 LTS,  and I want just to solve this problem on my pc